# code does not trigger the static execute method

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I call the static method `execute` and use the `$result` array ?

i have this code:

```
<?php
            $input_ = [
                'object_id' => $id,
            ];
            $results_wp_temp = ArticleLoadTagsData::execute($input_);
            if (
                    is_array($results_wp_temp) &&
                    !empty($results_wp_temp)
            ) {
                echo 'tags';
                foreach ($results_wp_temp as $result_wp_temp) {
                    ?>
                    <span><?php echo $result_wp_temp->name; ?></span>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                echo 'no tags';
            }
            ?>
```

and this class:

```
<?php

class ArticleLoadTagsData {

    public static function execute($input = []) {
        $result = [0=>1];
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: id does not trigger the execute function

Comment: but you haven't used the `$input` in your `execute()` method.

Comment: it doesnt matter, the function is not executed for some reason

Comment: has you included the class file when you want to use the class?

Comment: yes, i have included the file

Comment: Do you get some kind of an error? try turnning on E_ALL error reporting before call to this function